# How skewed does a distribution have to be before we use the median as the best measure of central tendency?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, skewness, median

The question is in the title. I'm mostly asking because I'm wondering whether this is subjective or not (this is regarding a sample like avg engineer salaries by state).

I know it's more appropriate to use the mean if the distribution is symmetric, or normal. But wouldn't all real life distributions be skewed, technically? What's a good rule of thumb here? When should I say, skewness value of $\pm \, x$ so the median is more representative of the average salary?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/when-does-the-amount-of-skew-or-prevalence-of-outliers-make-the-median-preferabl?rq=1

Comment: If you're after "average" salary, you're better off looking at the median - that would be a question of what could the average person expect to earn, rather than what is the average of the salaries.

Comment: The question is only resolved by clearly figuring out what you even *mean* by the vague phrase "central tendency" in your particular case. This is generally resolved by considering in explicit terms what you want to find out from your data. [If on the other hand your aim is simply to offer some quick summary of the data *don't restrict yourself to any single measure*; if means and medians and modes are substantively different, that's an important thing to know in a summary.]