# How i add uniformly distributed noisy attributes to data set?

Tags: normal-distribution, outliers, noise

I want to add some artificial outliers to my data set by follow same method below. 
so, how i can add contaminated data statistically to real data set like Pima Indians Diabetes?
info:
Pima Indians Diabetes:  768 instances    8  attributes
[enter link description here](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database)

Note:                                                                           I want steps not programming code.

> We have added uniformly distributed attributes as noisy attributes to data
>   sets [15]. To compare outlier detection and false alarm rate in our experiments we have planted 3% to 5% artificial outliers into real data sets according to the data sets domain knowledge (statistical characteristics like mean, standard
>   deviation, class distribution, type of attributes).
>   Blockquote

[enter link description here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S2212017312005713?token=8E82CA0DB558D48011F7C56B8F34E8CB164A98723E0F363F34C008AD30B632C33013DD6E8F70DAEC18B7237311E02F8C)

Comment: Hello.  Is this a statistics question (which would fit on this site) or a question about how to complete this task using certain software (which wouldn't fit)?

Comment: statistics question, i want steps to do statistically.ex: calculate mean or std

Comment: You may have a different impression, but really there is no universally accepted definition of "outlier."  Even the article you cite on outlier detection doesn't give much of a definition (based on a quick look); it talks about the need for outliers to meet certain criteria, and rather than specifying these it merely refers to another article ("13").  So it's not as if one could straightforwardly advise you create artificial values that are, e.g., >3.44 standard deviations from each variable's mean.  You'll need to come up with your own criteria.  Cheers ~

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7155/rigorous-definition-of-an-outlier

Comment: Thanks ,  how can  i create attributes that is 3.3 standard deviations from each variable's mean?   Take random sample from data set then add mean of data set+3.44 standard deviations of data set .

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to train a model that learns the distribution of each feature separately; it could be a KDE for each feature.

Then you could use this model to generate outliers for the data. I'd suggest producing the outliers by generating values at 4 std from the mean for a few of the features and generate realistic values for the rest. This will prevent the outliers to be too easily detectable.

Comment: Thanks.why this will prevent the outliers to be too easily detectable? .                       
If i calculate each feature mean and std separately ,then take random features and add mean and 4 std?

Comment: I think that the point should not be an outlier on all features. It's realistic if it is an outlier on one or two features alone. Yes that's what I'd do.

Comment: can do same rule for non normal distributed data?

Comment: I think that the point should not be an outlier on all features? can explain more please .you mean if i have point with 4 features ,for example add outlier for 2 of them better than all 4 features?