# Plot large high dimensional dataset

Tags: data-visualization, large-data, high-dimensional

I have a high dimensional dataset (12 variables) with 42000 observations.
I made a clustering and I found evidence that made me choose five clusters. So I want to plot my dataset with some tool to show these clusters (if it is possible).

I tried to use `Rtsne` package and I get this plot:

[image]

Are there other tools like this one for plotting these data to find some evidence for clustering?

Comment: "I tried to use Rtsne package and" — And what?

Comment: i get that plot

Comment: 12 variables isn't really that much. You should be able to use regular methods for visualizing datasets (possibly w/ some small adaptations) & get reasonable results. You can find some suggestions in my answer here: [How to extract information from a scatterplot matrix when you have large N, discrete data, & many variables?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144741/7290)