# Why jitter continuous value in a scatterplot?

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot

I'm using Orange Canvas and I generated a scatter plot. I have the possibility to jitter continuous variables but I really don't know why would I do that.

What's the idea behind jittering?

Comment: To deal with overprinting and hence give a less misleading visual impression. If you only have a few points you do not need to do it.

Comment: For a concrete example of jittering helping to see the patterns in data, see my answer here: [How to extract information from a scatterplot matrix when you have large N, discrete data, & many variables?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144741/7290)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This post](http://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/jitter.html) explains it well.

Often when you have a lot of overlapping points it can be hard to get a sense for their density. Two thousand points at (1, 1) appear the same as one point at (1, 1). Adding some jitter turns overlapping points into a smear and makes the density of points obvious.

Comment: Isn't it about discrete data, whereas the question explicitly asks about continuous data?

Comment: Adding to what @amoeba said this answer is correct when you add that that the continuous data we deal with is rounded due to measurement precision and so problems like described above occur.